# Prevent onClick getting fired on load. I'm using the functional component on a React project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

***This is the Parent Component which passes a reference to the cart component***

```
  function Header() {
    
      const cartRef = useRef();
    
      const handleClick = () =>{
        cartRef.current.style.boxShadow = "0 0 0 100vw rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.9)"
      }
    
        return (
                  <>
                    <Cart cRef={cartRef} onClick={()=>{handleClick()}}/>
                  </>
                );
      }
      
      export default Header;
```

**The Child Component assigns the reference to the div shown below**

```
    function Cart(props) {
    
        return (<>
                  <div ref={props.cRef}>
                     ...
                  </div>
            </>
        );
    }

export default  Cart;
```

Does passing references like this cause such issues?

Comment: Yes, it should work. We need more code than that to see what going on.

Comment: Can you please check it now. I added more code context.

Comment: Console.log `props.cRef` inside `Cart`. What values does `current` have?

Comment: It has the cart component. The issue isn't that it isn't working. Everything works fine, its just the initial onclick that gets fired and i'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this: `<Cart cRef={cartRef} onClick={handleClick}/>`

I think the `handleClick` fires because it's passed in a wrong way.

Comment: I just realized what was happening. I get so caught up on the event handler being the culprit totally forgetting about the rendering process. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The handleClick() isn't actually getting fired. Whats happening is that the Cart component that has been imported to the Header component will be visible like any component does when placed in the return statement.

```
function Header() {
    
      const cartRef = useRef();
    
      const handleClick = () =>{
        cartRef.current.style.visibility = "visible";
        cartRef.current.style.boxShadow = "0 0 0 100vw rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.9)"
      }
    
        return (
                  <>
                    <Cart cRef={cartRef} onClick={()=>{handleClick()}}/>
                  </>
                );
      }
      
      export default Header;
```

We can set the Cart component's ***Visibility*** to ***'hidden'*** and then on the handleClick() event handler, we set it back to ***'visible'*** again.